# Unable to configure k8 ingress on GKE to run solr

Tags: docker, kubernetes, solr, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to setup solr 8.0 on GKE. I can successfully run it on my local instance. But when I configured it on GKE, it keeps giving 502 error.

Here's my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: solr
  namespace: api
  labels:
    app: solr
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: solr
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: solr
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: solr:8
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8983
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
              memory: 512Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
              memory: 512Mi
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: solr
  namespace: api
  labels:
    app: solr
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: solr
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8983
  selector:
    app: solr
```

and ingress:

```
- host: solr.*****.***
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: solr
              port:
                name: http
```

Things I have tried so far:
I have tried running the service on different ports and default ports.
I can `exec` into pod and access solr through command line. It is working fine.
Using port-forwarding `kubectl port-forward --namespace api my-pod-name 8080:8983` I can access solr admin dashboard using the temporary url that google provides. But when i use the subdomain created for solr, it keeps giving me 502 Server error

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Logs display error `failed_to_pick_backend` when I open subdomain that I added.

Comment: You need to fix the port in the Ingress. The Service exposes port 8080 (name solr) but the Ingress references port http (default 80)

Comment: @boredabdel I have changed the ingress to use port 8080 (name solr) but it doesn't made any difference.

Comment: Some fields in the Ingress object doesn't take effect if you change them. You might need to delete and create everything again!

Comment: There is a health check failing. I had to manually edit it and add request path `/solr/#` which is my root path. After this, it works fine. How can i achieve this in yaml config, I have tried adding readiness probe and liveness probe. But that won't work, I have to manually edit the health check.

Comment: Aha that wasn't clear from the initial post. You can customize the healthCheck port and path deployed by the ingress using a BackenConfig object like this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#configuring_ingress_features_through_backendconfig_parameters